# Jmeter Error: Java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) at

Tags: sockets, azure, jmeter, cloud

***Jmeter Environment Details***
I am performing Jmeter testing on Microsoft Azure Cloud. I have created on VM(Virtual Machine) on the same cloud and from there I am hitting the application server on the same cloud environment. So in this case there is no network latency.

***Problem Statement:***
I am trying to run the load test for 300 users for 30 mins , but after 5 mins my script started failing, because of **Socket connection refused error**.

**My Analysis based on information available on net:**

I have read somewhere that this problem is because of limited socket connection limit on server, but when i run the same test from VM then my scripts run's just fine. so its definitely not server's issue. Can somebody please help me resolve this issue? Are there any settings needs to be done in jmeter, increase the socket connections?

**Actual Screenshot of Error**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qeihs.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely:

Looks like situation described at [Connection Reset since JMeter 2.10 ?](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed) wiki page. If you're absolutely sure that nothing is wrong with your server, you can follow the next recommendations:

1. Switch all your HTTP Request Samplers "Implementation" to be "HTTPClient4". The fastest and the easiest way of doing it is using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://blazemeter.com/blog/http-request-defaults).
2. Add the next lines to *user.properties* file (in JMeter's /bin folder)

   ```
   httpclient4.retrycount=1
   hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
   ```
3. Add (or uncomment and edit) the following line in *hc.parameters* file

   ```
   http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
   ```

Alternative assumption:

"Good" browsers send "Connection: close" with the last request to the web server. "Bad" browsers don't and keep connection open. You can control this behaviour via "Use KeepAlive" checkbox in the HTTP Request Sampler/Defaults. If it's unchecked - you can try ticking it.